# Multiple Stripe Transactions Parse Background Jobs

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, token, payment, stripe-payments

I'm using Parse to run a background job which will query a parse class and be given a list of Stripe tokens to charge. I've got the background job to easily make one charge however there's issues when multiple payments are present within the one job because of the calling of success/error. I require each stripe charge to give a success or error return so that I can then set the parse object as being paid or unpaid. I'm pretty inexperienced with JavaScript.

I'm able to make two charges successfully however can't get the success/error methods to return on the second stripe charge. Eventually I will want to run a 'for' method to iterate through various customer tokens to make bulk charges.

```
Parse.Cloud.job("makeCharge", function(request, status) {


  Stripe.Charges.create({
  amount: 1000 * 10, 
  currency: "usd",
  customer: "cus_customer1" client
},{
  success: function() {
    status.success("Purchase made!");
  },
  error: function() {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});
  Stripe.Charges.create({
  amount: 100000 * 10,
  currency: "usd",
  customer: "cus_customer2" 
},{
  success: function() {
    status.success("Purchase made!");
  },
  error: function() {
    status.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
  }
});

  });
```